# Filling in the gaps in an erotetic argument for pluralism about the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom

**Syntax assumption/stipulation.** I have decided to work with an erotetic function that is parenthetical. So I will not start with some proposition *A* and then have *A*? as its associated question, but I will have ¿*A*? for the association instead. I'm not sure this makes much difference in principle, but I don't have the best grasp on the theory of logical/mathematical parentheses anyway, though I recognize that I'll need to develop such a theory at some point (for example, to more strongly justify correlating ∈-notation with {}-notation).

**The argument:**

1. (¿℘(*n*)? = ¿2<sup>*n*</sup>?) :→ ¬(¿*n*<sup>*n*</sup>?, ¿*n*!?),
   *n* ≠ 0, *n* ≠ 2
2. ((¿℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)? = ¿2<sup>ℵ<sub>*a*</sub></sup>?) :→
   (¿ℵ<sub>*a*</sub><sup>ℵ<sub>*a*</sub></sup>?, ¿ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>!?))
3. ∀*n*(∃℘(*n*))
4. ¬∀ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>(∃℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>))
5. ∴ ¬(¿℘(*n*)? ≈ ¿℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)?)
6. (¬∀ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>(∃℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>))) →
   ∃ℵ<sub>β</sub>(¬(¿℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)? ≈ ¿℘(ℵ<sub>β</sub>)?))

[*gap/segue to a tangential deduction*]

1. ∀ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>(∃℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>) → ∃℘(℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)))
2. ¬∃℘(*V*)
3. ¿♢(℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>) ⇶ *V*)?
4. ¿♢(*V* = ℵ<sub>ω</sub>)?
5. *cf*(℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)) ≠ ℵ<sub>0</sub>
6. ∴ (¬♢(℘(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>) ⇶ *V*) ∨ ¬♢(*V* = ℵ<sub>ω</sub>))

**Intended interpretation of the argument.** The first section is supposed to show firstly that the powerset question for finite numbers is not the same as the powerset question for infinite numbers. Not just in the sense that there is one powerset function applied to different inputs, then, but that the powerset functions for finite and infinite numbers are not the same function in the first place. The "proof" is that the ℘-notation can be switched out for exponential, tetrationary, and factorial notation with respect to the alephs, whereas this interpolation is not admissible for finite numbers (except for 0 and 2, since 0! = 1 and 0<sup>0</sup> has been argued by some mathematicians to = 1, or then 2<sup>2</sup> is trivially tetrationary).

The next set of premises depends on a theory of "powerless cardinals" (for the mainline substrate of such a theory, see Gitman, et. al., ["What is the theory ZFC without power set?"](https://victoriagitman.github.io/files/ZFC-.pdf) and Matthews, ["Large Cardinals in Weakened Axiomatic Theories"](https://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/29589/1/Thesis.pdf)). My justification for asserting the existence of these cardinals is a reflection argument from premise (2) in the post-gap section of the argument (i.e., if the universe of sets is powerless, then by reflection there is a powerless set). "Therefore," it seems as though the powerset function applied to powerless cardinals is different from the powerset function applied to powerful ones. **But then the gap issue is: how does this show that there exist powerful cardinals that themselves fall under a plurality of powerset questions?** I need/want to show at least something like the following:

- ∃*AB*((*A* = ¿℘<sub>ψ</sub>(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)?) ≠ (*B* = ¿℘<sub>φ</sub>(ℵ<sub>*a*</sub>)?)

... where ψ and φ are different descriptors, e.g. ["definable" for the definable powerset function as opposed to the "full" such function](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/#SetThe).

I wrote down the "tangential" section while attempting to derive a difference between a powerset function that can be forced to give outputs that are the size of the universe of sets on the one hand, and a powerset function that can only be forced to yield set-sized powersets on the other. (*Note:* "*X* ⇶ *Y*" is to be read as, "*X* is forced to be *Y*.") However, this evolved into an outright tangent when it seemed as though I had instead come up with a quite separate argument either *for* the replacement axiom (to rule out setting *V* = ℵ<sub>ω</sub>) or *against* the permissibility of forcings that inflate powersets to class scale. At any rate, there still looks to be a decent gap between asserting class-sized forcing questions and asserting a plurality of set-sized forcing questions.

**Ambient problems.** Firstly, my own background justification for the powerset axiom seems to rule out powerless cardinals, and to in fact make powerlessness into one of the identifying features of *V* in itself. Such features do not admit of reflection (for example, *V* has the defining property of being universal over all sets, but this hardly allows us to reflect forth a set that is universal over all sets!). Secondly, by pushing more for parafoundational elements of sets modulo the Benacerraf problem, it seems possible to define *n*-like sets, sets meant to be correlated essentially with natural numbers, yet which have arbitrarily many parafoundational elements "on the side" and hence incalculable powersets above them. (For example, you could say that 1 = {0, *u*, *u*<sub>2</sub>, ... *u*<sub>ω</sub>}, where *u*'s are parafoundational ur-elements, whence the full powerset of 1 turns out to be the same size as the powerset of the zeroth aleph.)  More importantly for present purposes, what is the powerset of a Quine atom? Or then is the powerset function on sets that are elements of themselves, a different powerset function than the one on well-founded sets? Yet even if there is a distinctly parafoundational powerset function/question, how, if at all, does this contribute to deriving separate ψ's and φ's for well-founded powerset functions?

Lastly, in fact, then, I'm not even sure there's a need to *deduce* the multiplicity I'm looking for, or if this multiplicity is better taken for an axiom of the eventual intended system. I'm not sure that set theorists deduce that the definable powerset function is distinct from the full one, except in an indirect way, as when they deduce that *V* doesn't equal *L* because such an equation would wipe out measurable cardinals.

***Addendum.*** In case the above framing of the question seems too unfocused (it kind of seems that way to me), I offer the following specification:

> Would [many-sorted logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-many-sorted/) suffice to differentiate ψ and φ as desired?

Comment: I can't find any point of contact between what you wrote, and anything I know or have ever read about. I've read Hamkins and Woodin. They don't talk like this. Can you supply some contextual links? It it me? Am I missing some vast area of knowledge? Not just knowledge of, but knowledge about,  even at the level of reading papers I don't understand. A lot of your posts are like this. What am I missing? What does parafoundational mean?

Comment: @user4894 I just use "parafoundational" in place of "nonwell-founded" because the latter is clunky and the former fits with the use of words like "paraconsistent" and "paracomplete" (I know "antifounded" is another option, but that makes it seem like they're talking about sets that actively conflict with well-founded ones, but as [this Hamkins, et. al. essay discusses](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0814), it is possible to have a well-founded group of sets contained in a broader parafounded universe).

Comment: As for the use of erotetic logic, I have a faint feeling that Hintikka incorporates erotetic ideas into his "independence-friendly logic," and then has in mind some application to set theory (I think he's said there might be an IFL route to evaluating CH in a new way). One of my oldest questions on this SE had an accepted answer that IIRC described how erotetic considerations might be found in intuitionistic logic, too, and by that route might intersect set theory. Many-sorted logic is, to my knowledge, used in some class theories (MK and/or NBG, I'm not quite sure).

Comment: The equation *V* = the ωth aleph purportedly would obtain in ZFC without the replacement axiom scheme. The dissertation "Large Cardinals in Weakened Axiomatic Theories" allows for inflating powersets to the size of *V*. But normally, we hold that powersets cannot be cofinal with the zeroth aleph. So it seems as if we have to deny the permissibility of class inflation of powersets, or we have to deny *V* = the ωth aleph even if we suppress the replacement scheme (alternatively, we can derive that scheme in the event of the relevant denial).